# Debug log spits less amount of values. Any reason?

Tags: debugging

I tried running debug log on one of my controller. It spits all the debug statements and its values to the log. But suddenly the log size became too small and none my debug statements seems to be working.

Any workaround please? Thanks

Comment: Did you check the logging levels?

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson. I did not change anything. It was the same logging level that emits tons of debug texts to the log.

Comment: It seems to me that there is not enough detail in your question to make it answerable. Can you [edit] it to give us a better idea of what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have set up [Trace Flags](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_add_users_debug_log.htm&type=0) for the class you're trying to debug. Not only can you set up Debug Levels for Users, but you can also set them up for [Classes and for Triggers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_debug_log_classes.htm&type=0). Setting class and trigger trace flags doesn’t cause logs to be generated or saved. Class and trigger trace flags override other logging levels, including logging levels set by user trace flags, but they don’t cause logging to occur. If logging is enabled when classes or triggers execute, logs are generated at the time of execution.

When you're in the Debugger. there's generally, a DEVELOPER_LOG but there are also User Specific Logs both of which need to be configured (they're only valid for the time periods specified) along with class and trigger trace flags. If you're using User Specific logging when it expires, no logging will occur.